# How do I extract the output from CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay?

Tags: cgal

I am trying to convert a point cloud to a trimesh using `CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay()` and extract the data inside the trimesh to an OpenGL friendly format:

```
// The function below should set vertices and indices so that: 
// triangle 0: (vertices[indices[0]],vertices[indices[1]],vertices[indices[2]]), 
// triangle 1: (vertices[indices[3]],vertices[indices[4]],vertices[indices[5]]) 
// ...
// triangle n - 1
void reconstructPointsToSurfaceInOpenGLFormat(const& std::list<std::pair<Kernel::Point_3, Kernel::Vector_3>> points, // input: points and normals
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices, // output
    std::vector<unsigned int>& indices) { // output
   
    CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> trimesh;

    double spacing = 10;

    bool ok = CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay(points.begin(), points.end(),
        CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<std::pair<Kernel::Point_3, Kernel::Vector_3>>(),
        CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<std::pair<Kernel::Point_3, Kernel::Vector_3>>(),
        trimesh, spacing);

    // How do I set the vertices and indices values?
}
```

Please help me on iterating trough the triangles in trimesh and setting the vertices and indices in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Polyhedron_3` is not indexed based so you need to provide a item class with ids like [`Polyhedron_items_with_id_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__items__with__id__3.html). You will then need to call `CGAL::set_halfedgeds_items_id(trimesh)` to init the ids. If you can't modify the Polyhedron type, then you can use [dynamic properties](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html#title25) and will need to init the ids.

Note that [`Surface_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/) is indexed based and no particular handling is needed to get indices.

Comment: The trimesh is the output of `CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay()`. Does this mean that this algorithm does not produce indices? Can I assume that the 3 first vertices define the first triangle the next 3 the next triangle and so on? Or must I iterate over facets and then over vertices?

Comment: No, vertices are stored in a list. use `CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel,CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>` as polyhedron type and call the aforementioned function once the trimesh is filled.

Comment: Could I call CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay() with a CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> as output argument instead? But how do I extract the vertices and indices from this?

Comment: Yes you can use `Surface_mesh` as output. If you have a `Vertex_index`, then it is convertible to `std::size_t`. It is a model of [`Index` concept](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/STL_Extension/classIndex.html).

Comment: And such as std::size_t index can be used to look up a Kernel::Point_3? But how? I see no method like getPoint(size_t index) in Surface_mesh class.  Only thing I see is a vertices() method but this returns an iterator. Do I use std::advance() to increment this from the beginning to the index?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you.
you can write `for (SM::Vertex_index v : vertices(sm)) { sm.point(v); std::size_t vi=v; }` and `for (SM::Face_index f : faces(sm)){ for (SM::Vertex_index v : CGAL::vertices_around_face(halfedge(f, sm), sm)) { sm.point(v); std::size_t vi=v; }}` .

Answer (score 0):

Based on sloriots code from his answer:

```
void mesh2GLM(CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3>& trimesh, std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices, std::vector<int>& indices) {
    std::map<size_t, size_t> meshIndex2Index; 
    // Loop over all vertices in mesh:
    size_t index = 0;
    for (Mesh::Vertex_index v : CGAL::vertices(trimesh)) {
        CGAL::Epick::Point_3 point = trimesh.point(v);
        std::size_t vi = v;
        vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(point.x(), point.y(), point.z()));
        meshIndex2Index[vi] = index;
        index++;
    }

    // Loop over all triangles (faces):
    for (Mesh::Face_index f : faces(trimesh)) {
        for (Mesh::Vertex_index v : CGAL::vertices_around_face(CGAL::halfedge(f, trimesh), trimesh)) {
            trimesh.point(v);
            std::size_t vi = v;
            size_t index = meshIndex2Index[vi];
            indices.push_back(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Seems to work fine.